# MPI_ERR_BUFFER using MPI_Bsend() with large messages

Tags: c, mpi

I try to send large messages (integers) with `MPI_Bsend`. But if the message is greater than 1006 integers, I get the error "MPI_ERR_BUFFER: invalid buffer pointer". I tried attaching buffer with `MPI_Buffer_attach`, but it did not change a thing in the error message.

A minimal working example is

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  int world_rank, world_size;
  MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

  if (world_size < 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "World size must be greater than 1");
    MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 1);
  }

  int msg_size = 1007;
  int msg[msg_size];
  int i;

  int buf_size = 2^16;
  int buf[buf_size];
  MPI_Buffer_attach(buf, buf_size);

  if (world_rank == 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < msg_size; ++i) {
      msg[i] = rand();
    }

    MPI_Bsend(&msg, msg_size, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  }

  else if (world_rank == 1) {
    MPI_Recv(&msg, msg_size, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
  }
  MPI_Buffer_detach(&buf, &buf_size);
  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Can anybody give me a clue? Sorry if it's something obvious, I am new to MPI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of problems here!

First, your statement

```
int buf_size = 2^16;
```

sets buf_size to 16 and not 65536 (^ is bitwise XOR not "raise to power").

Second, the buffer size should be in bytes so the attach should be:

```
MPI_Buffer_attach(buf, buf_size*sizeof(int));
```

The main problem is that your send and receive don't match up - rank 1 should receive from rank 0:

```
MPI_Recv(msg, msg_size, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
```

whereas currently it tries to receive from itself.

David

Comment: Thanks for your help. What would then be the correct way to detach the buffer again - do I have to set `buf_size = buf_size*sizeof(int)` before I use  `MPI_Buffer_detach(&buf, &buf_size)`?

Comment: It would be better to define a new variable and set buf_size_bytes = buf_size * sizeof(int). Then you could use the same variable in both the attach and detach calls. Note that the model in MPI is *not* that you attach a buffer, send a message then immediately detach it. You are expected to attach the buffer near the start of your program, use it many times for lots of MPI_Bsend calls, then detach it near the end of your program.